# how to disconnect from googleapiclient in android

Tags: android, google-plus, android-googleapiclient

I am doing simple google login and logout using API. but when i logout using below code, sometimes googleapiclient not disconnect. and because of that when i am going for login, it will automatic login to my previous account rather that asking for select account.

Code for logout:

```
public void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.e("APPLICATION", "DISCONNECTED");

        }
```

when i call above method for logout, sometimes `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()` not called. help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new API try this:

```
    @Override
public void logOut() {
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        signOut();
        revokeAccess();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    App.logger().d(TAG, "signOut: status = " + status);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    App.logger().d(TAG, "revokeAccess: status = " + status);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After many memory leaks, this is what I came up with.  No more memory leaks.  Is it verbose? yes.  Is it too verbose? perhaps.  Does it work? yes.

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient !=null) if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(this);
 if (mGoogleApiClient !=null) mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
 if (mGoogleApiClient !=null) mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
 if (mGoogleApiClient !=null) if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
 mGoogleApiClient =null;
```